# PostgreSQL 9.6 parallel aggregates

Tags: postgresql, parallel-processing

PostgreSQL in version 9.6 adds support for parallel aggregates.

> With 9.6, PostgreSQL introduces initial support for parallel execution
>   of large queries. Only strictly read-only queries where the driving
>   table is accessed via a sequential scan can be parallelized. Hash
>   joins and nested loops can be performed in parallel, as can
>   aggregation (for supported aggregates). Much remains to be done, but
>   this is already a useful set of features.

- What are the supported aggregates mentioned above?
- Are there any special considerations when designing aggregate functions to allow usage of the parallel machinery?

Comment: Any function/aggregate that is marked as "parallel safe" will be considered when planning a query. See. `pg_proc.proparallel`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/catalog-pg-proc.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PostgreSQL 9.6 User-defined Aggregates documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/xaggr.html) now mentions parallel aggregates:

> 35.10.4. Partial Aggregation
>
> Optionally, an aggregate function can support partial aggregation. The
>   idea of partial aggregation is to run the aggregate's state transition
>   function over different subsets of the input data independently, and
>   then to combine the state values resulting from those subsets to
>   produce the same state value that would have resulted from scanning
>   all the input in a single operation. This mode can be used for
>   parallel aggregation by having different worker processes scan
>   different portions of a table. Each worker produces a partial state
>   value, and at the end those state values are combined to produce a
>   final state value. (In the future this mode might also be used for
>   purposes such as combining aggregations over local and remote tables;
>   but that is not implemented yet.)
>
> **To support partial aggregation**, the aggregate definition must provide
>   a combine function, which takes two values of the aggregate's state
>   type (representing the results of aggregating over two subsets of the
>   input rows) and produces a new value of the state type, representing
>   what the state would have been after aggregating over the combination
>   of those sets of rows. It is unspecified what the relative order of
>   the input rows from the two sets would have been. This means that it's
>   usually impossible to define a useful combine function for aggregates
>   that are sensitive to input row order.